# Expresso Store and iPhone 4

Tags: expresso-store

I have tested Expresso Store on an iPhone 4 (version 6.1.3) and it looks like add to cart is not working at all.

UPDATE:
I have tested Expresso Store on an iPhone 4 (version 7.0.3) and it works fine. Also tested on iPad 1 Gen (5.1.1) and OSX (10.6.8) os it looks like it is related to Safari from particular iOS version.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Is it working in Safari for PC or Mac? I can't test it since I don't have a iPhone running iOS6.x. Are you getting any errors? What's happening exactly!

Comment: No errors - when I click on "add to cart" is doing nothing. It works fine with iP5 (iOS7). Will test later with an iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Store is a server-side product, there are no differences between browsers.

Add to cart only requires that you submit a form to the server, which should work with even the most basic web browser.

I suspect if add to cart is not working on some devices, it's most likely related to the login status or stock level of that product, or possibly some client-side JS that you have implemented yourself.

Comment: I have tested it with Store Example as well - same results. For me it looks like issue with particular iOS/Safari version.

Comment: When you say it is "not working", what exactly happens? Does the page reload at all? If you include a `return=""` parameter does it redirect you there? I would hook it up to the Safari/Xcode debugger and see what is going on.

Comment: Well - add to cart is not adding items to cart. When I add `return="cart\checkout"` it shows that cart is still empty.

Comment: Does the page reload? Does it correctly redirect to the `cart/checkout` page?

Comment: Yes - it goes to `cart/checkout` page which in my case is a first step (page) in a checkout process.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like it's working properly then. My guess is that either the product is out of stock, or the `item_qty` field isn't being submitted correctly.

Comment: Product is in stock and item_qty exists (set by default to 1). Simple - is not working on that particular iOS version.

Comment: I too find this hard to believe that it's an issue with Store. Would you mind updating your question with the checkout tag and its contents from your template?